# The admin user sets value of user in the authentication context, but then that value is invisible to the actual component the value was set in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, components, react-context

the authentication component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
let userChosenByAdmin = '';

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  setUserChosenByAdmin: () => {},
  userChosenByAdmin,
});

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const setUserChosenByAdmin = (value) => {
    userChosenByAdmin = value;
    console.log(userChosenByAdmin); // this is printed with the right user email when I click on the email in the admin component, so in here it works
  };

  const contextValue = {
    setUserChosenByAdmin,
    userChosenByAdmin,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default AuthContext;
```

the admin component:

```
import {useContext } from 'react';
import AuthContext from '../store/auth-context';

const Admin = () => {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
  let chosenUser;

  const getUserInfo = async (e) => {
    chosenUser = await e.target.closest('h4').innerText; //this is an email address that is displayed on the page, and when I click on it, it prints the right value in the authentication context, but in this component it prints a blank line
    authCtx.setUserChosenByAdmin(chosenUser);
    console.log(authCtx.userChosenByAdmin); //prints blank line, but in the authentication context it prints the right value
return (
 <button onClick={getUserInfo}>get user info</button>
);
  };
```

so, when I click on the 'get user info' button, it print the user email I clicked on as the userChosenByAdmin value in the authentication context, but it prints a blank line in the Admin component.
I really need it to be visible in the Admin component and I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In such a scenarios you need to think in React perspective. Here, React doesn't actually knows that `userChosenByAdmin` is updated or not because it declared by using `let`.

Please try this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [userChosenByAdmin, setUserChosenByAdmin] = useState();

  const setUserChosenByAdmin = (value) => {
    setUserChosenByAdmin(value);
  };

  const contextValue = {
    setUserChosenByAdmin,
    userChosenByAdmin,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```